# Use of VBS for Data driven test on a website using Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, automation

I want to develop a VBS code which could do the following:

1. Start Internet Explorer.
   I believe this could be done by following:

   Set IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_")
     IE.Visible = True
     IE.Navigate "THE SITE URL HERE"
2. Grab value from Column 1, Row 1 from an excel sheet, and input it to the "Name" Text input field.
3. Grab value from Column 2, Row 1 from an excel sheet and accordingly select a drop down value.
4. Click the Submit button.

I can get the tag names using firebug to submit values.
I believe this question has been asked before (Dont take out your Nerf guns yet), but none of the solutions pointed me to the right direction.

If anyone out there could point me to the right direction, it would be greatly helpful.

Comment: Please try solving this yourself first, and come back when you have a *specific* question. As it is, your question not only is too broad, but it also doesn't show any effort of your own.

Comment: Yes it is doable and a nice way to practice with writing your own testrunner. Maybe you would want to switch to Excel VBA: Now you can use the worksheets to create a datatable or even keywords to drive your test with. And if you add `IE` as a reference to VBA, you also get intellisense on the InternetExplorer object as a bonus.